# Show/Hide Modal Popup in User Control from ASPX behind code

Tags: c#, asp.net, modalpopupextender, webusercontrol

I need to show/hide a reusable modal popup that it is in a UserControlWeb (ascx).

In my ASPX web, I defined the UC:

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="uc" TagName="uc1" Src="~/Controls/modalpopup.ascx" %>
<uc:uc1 ID="ModalPopup1" runat="server" />
```

I can show/hide the modalpopup with javascript:

```
$find('MBehavior').show();
$find('MBehavior').hide();
```

But, I need to do from behind code of my ASPX web.

It is posible?

Answer (score 0):

Try the above

```
 string script = @"  <script type=""text/javascript""> 
                  $find('MBehavior').show();
                });</script>";
            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "", script);
```

Comment: I need to do without PostBack. Works this code without PostBack?

Comment: Nope. I did't know that you need it with out postback.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe if you have updatepanel in your page you can try;

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(updatePanelID, updatePanelID.GetType(), Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), "$find('MBehavior').show(); $find('MBehavior').hide();", true);
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to to run from aspx:

```
$("#mybutton").click(function(e) {
      $find('MBehavior').show();
      $find('MBehavior').hide();
      e.preventDefault();
    });
```

if from code behind:

```
$("#mybutton").click(function(e) {
$.ajax( {
type:'Get',
url:'aspxfilename/mymethod',
success:function(data) {

}

});
e.preventDefault();
});
```

and in .cs file create a method:

```
[WebMethod]
public static string mymethod()
{
//run javascript
}
```